# Making an image jump up (and fall back)

Tags: javascript, image, animation

I am making a platform game in JavaScript and I need some help.

How do I make an image jump up `50px` in JavaScript when the spacebar pushed then fall back to a certain position?

Answer (score 4):

If you mean jumping as in jumping with gravity - you'd need a parabola formula.

E.g.: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/7JFU3/.

```
var x = 0;

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    x++;
    image.style.top = 50 - (-0.1 * x * (x - 50)) + 'px';

    if(x >= 50) clearInterval(interval);
}, 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on exact the same thing. Here's my github project link https://github.com/beothorn/webcomicsgame

Look at MainCharacter.js at

```
if(gameCommandState.up){
    if(this.canJump(game))
      this.element.yAccelerate(-this.yAcceleration);
}
```

You can fork it if you want, but I'm doing it using canvas.

Answer (score 0):

We had fun extending this to have an image keep bouncing up and down

var x = 0;
              var goingUp = true;

```
          var interval = setInterval(function() {
              if(goingUp==true) {
                x++;
                if(x >= 50) {
                    goingUp=false;
                    //alert("go down")
                }
              } else {
                x--;
                if(x <= -50) {
                    goingUp=true;
                    //alert("go up")
                }
              }
              $('#demo').css('top', 50 - (-0.1 * x * (x - 50)));
          }, 20);
```